# Which verb goes with "achievement"

Tags: verbs

I am writing a research paper and I'm trying to figure to which one goes with achievement can somebody please help me?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Asking for a list of verbs—and also not providing a complete sentence—is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some verbs that go with achievement:

- accomplish an achievement
- obtained an achievement
- attained an achievement

Comment: Can we also say "make an achievement"?

Comment: @dan I don't think I've heard anyone use that

Answer (score 0):

There is also the verb **achieve** to be considered as an alternative to **{verb} an achievement**.  You may actually be looking for a noun or noun phrase to complement the verb **achieved** :)